# mysql - offset problem

Tags: mysql, syntax, offset

I recently posted a question about getting last 3 results in table in the correct order. I now want the get all comments apart from the last 3 in the correct order.

Here is my syntax;

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM $table 
      ORDER BY ID DESC 
      OFFSET 3) AS T 
ORDER BY TIME_STAMP
```

The error I am receiving is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OFFSET, 3) AS T ORDER BY TIME_STAMP' at line 1

I can't seem to get it to work. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html#id3294320):

> To retrieve all rows from a certain
>   offset up to the end of the result
>   set, you can use some large number for
>   the second parameter. This statement
>   retrieves all rows from the 96th row
>   to the last:

They recommend you use a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
```

So in your case, you should try:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM $table 
      ORDER BY ID DESC 
      LIMIT 3,18446744073709551615) AS T 
ORDER BY TIME_STAMP
```

Note that you can also use the PostgreSQL compatible version using the keyword `OFFSET`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM $table 
      ORDER BY ID DESC 
      LIMIT 18446744073709551615 OFFSET 3) AS T 
ORDER BY TIME_STAMP
```

Just in case you are wondering, `18446744073709551615 = 2^64 - 1`.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for the opposite. Getting all the records except for the last 3.

Comment: @Daniel: That's what this statement does. It skips the first 3 and returns the rest.

Comment: Actually, that query can do whichever you want simply by replacing DESC with ASC :)

Comment: @Nicholas: You would need to know how many rows to select if you reverse the ordering so that you don't get the last 3 (i.e. count - 3).

Comment: I had to change the offset to 3 but perfect.

Comment: @eagle: Interesting... I wasn't aware of this :) +1

Comment: @eagle: Right, I meant with regard to Daniel's comment (as I interpreted it), you can use your query to get all but the _last_ 3 _or_ all but the _first_ 3 just by changing DESC/ASC.

Comment: @Nicholas: my bad, I assumed you were talking to me since I didn't see an @ in your comment.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use OFFSET without a LIMIT.

A little bulky, but that query worked for me, and not worked without an redundant internal subquery (mysql 5.0.90)

```
select * from $table 
where id not in (
  select id from (
    select id from languages order by id DESC LIMIT 3
  ) l1
) order by time_stamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue because I copied:

```
OFFSET :offset LIMIT :limit
```

from an existing query, which is valid in Postgres.

Apparently the order matters in MySQL, so reversing the order worked for me:

```
LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset
```