# select a range of values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How would I select all but the first 3 rows in my MySql query?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE approved = 1");
```

Comment: According to what criterion do you define "first"?

Comment: Well i'd like it to be work regardless of how I ordered or sorted it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql Offset Infinite rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255517/mysql-offset-infinite-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE approved = 1 LIMIT 3,SOME_HUGE_NUMBER
```

[See this post for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059634/mysql-offset-problem/3059670#3059670)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the following:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE approved = 1");
$rowCount = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rowCount = $rowCount + 1;
    // do stuff only if you have reached the third row.
    if ($rowCount > 3){
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments
                                     WHERE approved = 1 
                                     ORDER BY columnName 
                                     LIMIT 3");
```

To find third record order by columnName use

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments
                                     WHERE approved = 1 
                                     ORDER BY columnName 
                                     LIMIT 2, 1");
```

To find All other than 1st 3 rows  use `LIMIT 2, total_no_of_rows`

if you don't know total_no_of_rows use very large number instead of it.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments
                                     WHERE approved = 1 
                                     ORDER BY columnName 
                                     LIMIT 2, total_no_of_rows");
```

Comment: This is all but the first *2*.